# Login sent in plaintext over SSL?

Tags: java, eclipse, ssl, authentication, zap

I was testing my website with SSL enabled and disabled with OWASP ZAP (A proxy used for local browser traffic sniffing) and noticed that my login is sent in plaintext both over HTTPS and HTTP. Is there a way to prevent this?

I am using Tomcat 8 and Eclipse Mars as the Java IDE for writing the site.
(Image below, as I do not have enough rep to submit it properly)
https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/1N0h1l0K12470p2K123s/Image%202015-04-02%20at%202.52.00%20AM.png

Comment: HTTPS is not plaintext.

Comment: Is there a way to prove that, and prove it cannot be grabbed by somebody on the local network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misinterpreting what you're seeing -- or, perhaps more precisely, you're not taking into account the implications of where you're seeing it.

By definition, it something is being sent over HTTPS, it's not in plaintext.

OWASP ZAP is the wrong tool to observe this with, since it's designed to be able to crack open an SSL connection in the middle, for purposes of observation... but this man-in-the-middle approach can't be done [without your complicity](https://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/wiki/HelpUiDialogsOptionsDynsslcert).

A more appropriate tool to see that your traffic is indeed not in plaintext would be a packet sniffer, like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), where the difference between HTTP and HTTPS will be apparent and obvious.